# How to get the count of a pair of field values?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I need to build a heatmap from the data I have in elasticsearch. The heatmap is the count of cases where two specific fields have the same value. For the data

```
{'name': 'john', 'age': '10', 'car': 'peugeot'}
{'name': 'john', 'age': '10', 'car': 'audi'}
{'name': 'john', 'age': '12', 'car': 'fiat'}
{'name': 'mary', 'age': '3', 'car': 'mercedes'}
```

I would like to get the number of unique pairs for the values of `name` and `age`. That would be

```
john, 10, 2
john, 12, 1
mary, 3, 1
```

I could get all the events and make the count myself but I was hoping that there would be some magical aggregation which could provide that.

It would not be a problem to have it in a nested form, such as

```
{
  'john':
    {
      '10': 2,
      '12': 1
    },
  'mary':
    {
      '3': 1
    },
}
```

or whatever is practical.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Inner aggregation`. Use query like

```
POST count-test/_search
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
  "group By Name": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "name"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "group By age": {
           "terms": {
              "field": "age"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

Output won't be like as you mentioned but like.

```
"aggregations": {
  "group By Name": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "john",
           "doc_count": 3,
           "group By age": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "10",
                    "doc_count": 2
                 },
                 {
                    "key": "12",
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "mary",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "group By age": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "3",
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
      ]
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a term aggregation with a script:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation

Like this you can "concat" what you want such as :

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "data" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "doc['name'].value + doc['name'].age",
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Not sure about the string concat syntax).

Comment: That would have been a fantastic solution but I get an error despite going along the docs (I use ES 5.0 and the docs you pointed to are labelled "current"). I get a `"type": "parsing_exception","reason": "[terms] failed to parse field [script]"` which I do not understand -- it seems like `script` is not recognized by `terms`(as a correct parameter)

Comment: Yes it supports it from 2.4 (you can change the version in the doc).  As you can see for version 5.0, this it not ``source`` but ``inline``.